# laravel relationship without foreign key

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, relationship

Imagine in Laravel project I have `Traking` `Order` and `Driver`  Eloquent models.

In `trakings` table I have column `tracking_key`. in `drivers` table I also have column `tracking_key`.

For example if drivers `tracking_key` is x, there are many tracking information with `tracking_key` x inside `trakings` table.

So now I have `$order = new Order::with('driver')`; It works fine, But now in this query I want to get information from `trakings` table too (traking information inside `trakings` table that matches driver's `tracking_key`).

As you can see I can't have `Driver::with('trakings')` type of relationship as I have no foreign keys in these two tables.

I tried:

```
$order = new Order::with(['driver' => function($query){
    $query->join('trackings', 'trackings.tracking_key', '=', 'drivers.tracking_key');
}])
```

But result was stranje and I think this doesn't work. So what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

you can use nested eager load like this :

```
Order::with('driver.trackings')
```

this it will be load driver related to order and trackings related to driver

Comment: I can't have trackings() relationship inside driver